# How do I convert a series of mixed text and number values to a single string with consecutive number values summed?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For values:

```
1, 1, A, B, 2, 1, C, C, 3, D, 1, 1, 1
```

How would a create a single string:

```
2AB3CC3D3 (not 11AB21CC3D111)
```

Comment: Are the values in different cells in one row or one column?  Is it always the same number of cells?

Comment: Are the AB, CC and D always in the same position?

Comment: It would help if you would give more context, more examples and their outcomes?

Comment: The values are in the same row. Each cell might be either a number or text.

Comment: Then this will require vba.

Comment: @AlexRiley are the values split across columns though or is the value you’ve shown in a single cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Public Function SummateAllNumbers(ByVal rngCells As Range, Optional ByVal bSplitCellContents As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal strDelimiter As String = ",") As String
    Dim rngCell As Range, arrValues() As String, lngIndex As Long, arrSplitValues() As String
    Dim i As Long, lngSummation As Long, strValue As String

    lngIndex = -1

    For Each rngCell In rngCells
        If bSplitCellContents Then
            arrSplitValues = Split(rngCell.Value, strDelimiter)
        Else
            arrSplitValues = Split(rngCell.Value)
        End If

        For i = 0 To UBound(arrSplitValues)
            lngIndex = lngIndex + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrValues(lngIndex)
            arrValues(lngIndex) = arrSplitValues(i)
        Next
    Next

    For i = 0 To UBound(arrValues)
        strValue = Trim(arrValues(i))

        If IsNumeric(arrValues(i)) Then
            lngSummation = lngSummation + strValue
        Else
            If lngSummation > 0 Then
                SummateAllNumbers = SummateAllNumbers & lngSummation
            End If

            SummateAllNumbers = SummateAllNumbers & strValue
            lngSummation = 0
        End If

        If i = UBound(arrValues) And lngSummation > 0 Then
            SummateAllNumbers = SummateAllNumbers & lngSummation
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

... you need add the above to a new Module with the VBA Editor.

You can use it 3 ways.

**Single Cell Delimited**

[image: Single Cell Method]

You can specify it against a single cell and have the function split the contents of the cell into an array so as to identify individual elements.

**Range Selection**

[image: Range Selection]

Omit the part of the formula that specifies that you want to split the contents of the cell by a specific delimiter and select a range of cells.

**Combination of Both**

[image]

You can do both.

If you don't see it, there's also a 3rd parameter to change the delimiter if you need that option.

I didn't get your answer to whether or not the values are in different cells so I catered for both.

I hope it works for you.